# Thymeleaf: Error resolving template "scripts/.."

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I Have a spring-boot application with thymeleaf, the issue is already raised here http://forum.thymeleaf.org/CSS-and-JS-Not-Resolving-td4028878.html. The application was working fine today stopped for some reason. I am using spring-boot out of the box configuration.

For All my scripts and styles thymyleaf tries to resolve it as a template which is strange. for example here an error when I try to get jquery

```
{"timestamp":1454200386383,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException","message":"Error resolving template \"scripts/jquery.min\", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers","path":"/scripts/jquery.min.js"}
```

Here are my config

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.")
public class MvcWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
MessageRepository repository;

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MvcWebConfig.class);
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
    "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/static/images/", "classpath:/static/css/"};

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}


@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

@Bean(name = "localeResolver")
public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    Locale defaultLocale = new Locale("en");
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(defaultLocale);
    return localeResolver;
}

@Bean
public DatabaseDrivenMessageSource messageSource() {
    DatabaseDrivenMessageSource messageSource = new DatabaseDrivenMessageSource();
    messageSource.setRepository(repository);
    messageSource.reload();
    return messageSource;
}
```

Here my security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService userService;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**", "/css/**", "/images/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index", "/login","/career", "/contact", "/error").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll();
    http.csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userService);
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
    return repository;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your configuration

Comment: You are actually not using the out-of-the-box configuration due to the `@EnableWebMvc` which indicates you are configuring things yourself. Remove that as well as the `addResources` as those are then configured by Spring Boot.

Comment: You are right, I do nit need the @EnableWebMvc. Also, I have removed the resources which made the code cleaner. But the issue was not caused by this misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in one of the request mapping as follows

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

it should be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

I do not know more details what has happened behind the scene, but the error message also was not very informative about the error root cause.